# Splitting up a Texture and Object into different parts

Tags: mesh, texturing, objects

I was wondering if it is possible to split an object's texture/UV map after splitting an object in Blender i.e. splitting a full body mesh's map into legs, hips, etc. and how would I do it if it is possible?

[image]
For example, I need the lower jaw to have its own texture. I have no idea how to do it or go about it though.

[image]
The texture isn't just for the lower jaw, so when I export the object, there isn't a fitting texture for it.

Or is there another program that does this automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Separating Texture Maps

You can bake textures from one object to another. If the objects are already separated (as it seems to be in your case) it makes things easier.

### 1. Separating the Object to which you want to bake the new texture.

- Tab into Edit Mode and select all faces of the mesh you want to have in a separate object.
- hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate the selection.
- hit <kbd>P</kbd> and select "Selection" to create a new object from your selected faces.

[image: create duplicate from the mesh part]

### 2. Preparing new Objct

- Select your newly created object, (tab into object mode, if otherwise) go to "Properties - Materials" and delete the material.

[image: delete material of cloned object part]

- With you newly created object, tab into Edit Mode and create a new texture of the size you desire (also pack the islands and correct the margins, if you want)*.

[image: create new texture]

### 3. Bake texture from Original to new Object

- Select the original object.
- Shift>+Select the new Object.
- Go to "Properties - Render - Bake", select "Textures", turn on "Selected to Active" and hit "Bake".
- Don't forget to save the new texture map after baking.

[image: Bake Texture]

Create a new material for your newly created object and assign the Texture(s) to it. You can then go to the original object and delete the part from which we created the copy in Step 1.

*Be aware, that changing the UV size as well as the size of the new texture might result in visible texture differences between the original and the new object.